# mdframed example throwing error

Tags: mdframed

I'm trying to get the following `mdframed`example from the [package documentation](http://ctan.uib.no/macros/latex/contrib/mdframed/mdframed.pdf) to work (`mdframed-example-default` page 5), but it's throwing the following errors

```
Missing number, treated as zero T
Illegal unit of measure (pt inserted) T
```

and displays a peculiar "pt" before printing the environment contents with the title box positioned too low. How to fix this? The title box should be just on the middle of the top line.

```
\documentclass{article}

\usepackage{tikz,mdframed}

\begin{document}

\mdfsetup{skipabove=\topskip,skipbelow=\topskip}
\newcounter{theo}[section] 
\newenvironment{theo}[1][]{%
\stepcounter{theo}% 
    \ifstrempty{#1}% 
    {\mdfsetup{%
        frametitle={%
            \tikz[baseline=(current bounding box.east),outer sep=0pt]
            \node[anchor=east,rectangle,fill=blue!20]
            {\strut Theorem~\thetheo};}}%
    }%
    {\mdfsetup{% 
        frametitle={%
            \tikz[baseline=(current bounding box.east),outer sep=0pt]
            \node[anchor=east,rectangle,fill=blue!20]
            {\strut Theorem~\thetheo:~#1};}}%
    }%
    \mdfsetup{innertopmargin=10pt,linecolor=blue!20,%
            linewidth=2pt,topline=true,
            frametitleaboveskip=\dimexpr−\ht\strutbox\relax,}
    \begin{mdframed}[]\relax%
    }{\end{mdframed}}

\begin{theo}
    This is an example theorem
    %
    \begin{equation}
        a^2 + b^2 = c^2
    \end{equation}
\end{theo}

\end{document}
```

resulting in

[image]

Answer (score 6, accepted):

The line

```
frametitleaboveskip=\dimexpr−\ht\strutbox\relax
```

has a strange character (probably a result of the copy-paste process) just before `\ht` that must be replaced by a standard minus sign:

```
frametitleaboveskip=\dimexpr-\ht\strutbox\relax
```

The code:

```
\documentclass{article}

\usepackage{tikz,mdframed}

\mdfsetup{skipabove=\topskip,skipbelow=\topskip}
\newcounter{theo}[section] 
\newenvironment{theo}[1][]{%
\stepcounter{theo}% 
    \ifstrempty{#1}% 
    {\mdfsetup{%
        frametitle={%
            \tikz[baseline=(current bounding box.east),outer sep=0pt]
            \node[anchor=east,rectangle,fill=blue!20]
            {\strut Theorem~\thetheo};}}%
    }%
    {\mdfsetup{% 
        frametitle={%
            \tikz[baseline=(current bounding box.east),outer sep=0pt]
            \node[anchor=east,rectangle,fill=blue!20]
            {\strut Theorem~\thetheo:~#1};}}%
    }%
    \mdfsetup{innertopmargin=10pt,linecolor=blue!20,%
            linewidth=2pt,topline=true,
            frametitleaboveskip=\dimexpr-\ht\strutbox\relax,}
    \begin{mdframed}[]\relax%
    }{\end{mdframed}}

\begin{document}

\begin{theo}
test
    \begin{equation}
        a^2 + b^2 = c^2
    \end{equation}
\end{theo}

\end{document}
```

[image]